# The difference between $\int$ and $d()$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I got these wrong on a test, where I was given what is inside $d()$:

- $d(\sin x) = -\cos x$
- $d(\cos x) = \sin x$
- $d(\tan x) = \ln(\sec x)$
- $d\left(\frac{1}{4}x^4\right) = \frac{1}{20}x^5$

I got them all wrong; I was under the assumption that this:

- $d(\sin x) = -\cos x$
   Meant the same as this:
- $\int(-\cos x)\ dx = \sin x + c$ 

  Was I right, and just lost points for not including the "$dx$" after "$-\cos x$", or do these two symbols mean something different?

Comment: You were right and lost points for not including $dx$

Comment: @TonyS.F.: Pay attention to the actual results, there's more error than that!

Comment: No, It is not correct that $d(\sin x)= - \cos x$, actually, it is $d(\sin x)=\cos x \, dx$ and $\int \cos x \, dx = \sin x$

Answer (score 1):

Issues of forgetting $\mathrm{d}x$ aside, you seem to have mixed up what $\int$ and $\mathrm{d}$ refer to. You appear to have *integrated* to compute $\mathrm{d}()$, and *differentiated* to compute $\int()$. But the meaning of the symbols is the other way around; $\mathrm{d}()$ is differentiation, and $\int()$ is integration.

e.g. it's $\mathrm{d}(x^7) = 7x^6 \mathrm{d}x$ and $\int x^7 \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{8} x^8 + C$, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, and the derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$. It does not seem like the $dx$ is the most important mistake. I have a strong feeling you have swapped the operations of integration and derivation.